# adding html text to my UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I want to add text from my database to a UIWebView, but I have an error I can't deal with.

in my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface readNotice : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *message;
IBOutlet UIWebView *body;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UILabel *message;
@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIWebView *body;

-(void)getNoticeData:(NSString *)noticeID:(NSString *)noticeTitle;

@end
```

In the .m:

```
@synthesize message,body;

-(void)getNoticeData:(NSString *)noticeID:(NSString *)noticeTitle {


//some taks not useful for this code


NSString *bodyText = [dict objectForKey:@"introtext"];

[body loadHTMLString: bodyText];
}
```

The error I get:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'loadHTMLString:'
```

why is this happening? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct call would be `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

Answer (score 7):

try using like this

> NSString *html = @"Should be halfI wish the answer were just 42";
>       [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

Comment: That won't work because you need the html and body tags: *html = @"<html><body>Text goes here.</body></html>".